# Сложные слова с союзом "и"

Tags: сложные-слова

Сложные слова могут образовываться сложением слов. Например: маляр-штукатур, повар-кондитер, кресло-кровать.

Бывает, сложное слово состоит из трёх и более слов. А может ли в такое написание их через дефис включаться союз "и"? Осы - рабочие и трутни. В таком случае могут ли "трутни" восприниматься принадлежащими к сложному слову?

Comment: Пробелы вокруг дефиса не делаются.

Comment: Да, теперь ясно, спасибо.

Comment: Именно сейчас прочитали или раньше? Мне интересно узнать, приходило ли оповещении о том комментарии?

Comment: Сейчас. Не обо всех комментариях ко мне почему-то поступают оповещения.

Comment: Почитайте, когда ставят наращения, Владимир.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое правило:

все слова пишутся раздельно, если при определяемом существительном имеются два нераспространенных приложения, соединенные союзом И, например:

студенты филологи и журналисты (то есть студенты-филологи и студенты-журналисты)

депутаты консерваторы и либералы (депутаты-консерваторы и депутаты-либералы).

То же, если при двух определяемых существительных имеется общее приложение, например:

студенты и аспиранты филологи (то есть студенты-филологи и аспиранты-филологи).

В вашем случае: осы рабочие и трутни (то есть осы-рабочие и осы-трутни).

Answer (score 0):

Может, но такое редко происходит.

Лучший пример - это слово "Рок-н-ролл". "н" - сокращение от "and", что в переводе означает "и".

Comment: А "осы-рабочие и трутни" воспринимается как "осы-рабочие" и "трутни" и ни в коем случае как "осы-рабочие" и "осы-трутни"?

Comment: Максимум 3 слова. А с 4 словами вроде бы и не видел никогда.

Comment: Через дефис могут писаться слова, когда это два в одном. А пчёлы же являются или рабочими, или трутнями. Но не 2 в 1. И такие сложные слова, как правило, зафиксированы в словарях. Да и при этом **все** слова пишутся через дефис. Дефис не присоединяет фразы.

Comment: А если их употребить в собирательном смысле? Как бы объединить их таким образом в одно понятие.

Comment: 2 варианта: "осы — рабочие и трутни" или "осы (рабочие и трутни)".

Comment: Вот. О возможности первого варианта я и спрашивал. Просто "трутней" читатель может отнести к следующему слову, не принадлежащему "осам". Иногда это важно: человек-крестьянин и охотник. "Охотник" может пониматься как другой человек.

Comment: Но это не дефис, а тире. И это будет не сложное слово, а уточнение.