# Сложение слова и словосочетания

Tags: словообразование

Можно ли образовывать новые сложные слова соединением слова и словосочетания?

Пример: состояние-лицо кирпичом.

Владимир изобразил состояние-лицо кирпичом.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454575/Сложные-слова-с-союзом-и

Comment: Да, но всё-таки отличается.

Comment: Состояние лицо-кирпичом. Так уклюже будет.

Comment: @shampar Корректно так: *состояние "лицо кирпичом"*. Но это мимика, а не состояние. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/81014/морда

Comment: То была идея по поводу мысли непременно тиснуть дефис в то, что есть.